# What namespace to use to recognize nav tag in JSF 2.x?

Tags: namespaces, taglib

I was asked to use externally provided css/js for web application I am working (JSF 2.x). When I added nav tag into a foo.xhtml file, IDE (eclipse) generated a warning(?) saying - "Unknown tag (nav)."

The foo.xhtml file has following xml namespaces of taglib at top:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

I assume html taglib does not understand nav tag which is introduced in html 5. How can I rectify this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 support is available only in jsf 2.2 afterwards, it will not work in JSF 2.0 so be sure to use the 2.2 version.

By the way, replace the old java.sun.com with xmlns.jcp.org and include

```
xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

There are several ways to use it, most of them described in this [article](http://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/jsf_2_2_and_html).